# How to do substring search in Postgres on column which has non English characters?

Tags: postgresql, pattern-matching

I can use trigram to do a substring search on columns with English characters but when I try to do it with columns with Thai characters, it doesn't work (it was very slow).

The doc says pg_trgm ignores non-word characters (non-alphanumerics) when extracting trigrams from a string. (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html)

Is there a way to do a substring search on non-alphanumeric characters on Postgres?

Comment: What is the encoding and ctype of your database?  What version are you using?  Do the results seem correct but slow, or not even correct?

Comment: @jjanes Changing LC_TYPE from C to C.UTF-8 fixed the issue. pg_trgrm extension ignores non-alphanumeric characters and after changing the LC_TYPE, it starts considering Thai characters as alphanumeric characters as well.